Python/VScode 'continue' causes rest of loop code to be grayed out
I have the following Python code (in VScode IDE):
def parse_seeyou_waypoints(lines, bounds=None):
    waypoint_list = WaypointList()
    cherrypy.log('in parse_seeyou_waypoints function:')

    #gfp 241210: modified to wait for header line before processing
    #gfp 241210: added 'ISO-8859-2' decoding for correct cherrypy logging display

    #gfp 241208 added to print out all lines in selected .CUP file
    # wpnum = 0
    # for byteline in lines:
    #     wpnum = wpnum + 1
    #     line = byteline.decode('ISO-8859-2')

    header = 'name,code,country,lat,lon,elev,style,rwdir,rwlen,freq,desc'

    wpnum = 0
    for byteline in lines:
        wpnum = wpnum + 1
        line = byteline.decode('ISO-8859-2') #gfp 241210: added 'ISO-8859-2' decoding for correct cherrypy logging display
        line = line.strip()

        # cherrypy.log('in for loop: wpnum = %s line = %s' %(wpnum, line))
        cherrypy.log(f'for loop row {wpnum}: {line}')

        if header != line: #gfp 241210: modified to skip blank lines before header line
            continue
        else:
            cherrypy.log(f'header line found at row {wpnum}: {line}')
            continue #skip to next line (first waypoint line)

        #check for other possible .cup sections?
        if line == "" or line.startswith("*"):
            continue

        if line == "-----Related Tasks-----":
            cherrypy.log('In -----Related Tasks----: line = %s' % line)

            break

        cherrypy.log('in for loop before line = __CSVLine(line): wpnum = %s' %wpnum)

        fields = []
        line = __CSVLine(line)
        cherrypy.log('in for loop after line = __CSVLine(line): wpnum = %s' %wpnum)

        while line.has_next():
            fields.append(next(line))
            cherrypy.log('in while line.has_next():line = %s' %line)

        #display fields for this line
        cherrypy.log('extracted fields for line = %s' %wpnum)
        idx = 0
        for field in fields:
            cherrypy.log(' field[%s]: %s' % (wpnum, field))

As it stands above, all code below
else:
    cherrypy.log(f'header line found at row {wpnum}: {line}')
    continue #skip to next line (first waypoint line)

Is grayed out (i.e. VSCode says it is unreachable), and in AFAICT doesn't execute at all.  However, if I comment out the 'continue' statement in the 'else:' block, then the rest of the function is 'reachable'.
What am I doing wrong here?

Both the if and else have continue - meaning a continue will always happen and the code below it can never be reached.

OK, so I'm an idiot. Thanks for taking the time to point out the obvious to me :)

Recommended reading: Section 4.4 of this document

The issue with the provided code lies in the structure of the if-else block and the use of continue statements. Both branches of the if-else block lead to a continue statement, meaning that the code within the loop will always move to the next iteration without executing any subsequent code.
Maybe you are mixing up with the pass statement that does nothing. It seems like you would like to use this instead:
if header != line: #gfp 241210: modified to skip blank lines before header line
    pass
else:
    cherrypy.log(f'header line found at row {wpnum}: {line}')
    continue #skip to next line (first waypoint line)

Overall, you might just invert your condition and do this:
if header == line: #gfp 241210: modified to skip blank lines before header line
    cherrypy.log(f'header line found at row {wpnum}: {line}')
    continue #skip to next line (first waypoint line)
# no else needed

Now, the code below it is reachable. Only for the header, line will be skipped.
